# Djangoでcssが反映されません

Tags: python, html, css, django

Djangoのcssファイルが反映されません.
ご教授お願い致します.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  {% load static %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 
'class_review/style.css' %}" />
<title>CLASS REVIEW</title>
</head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<body>
  <h1>CLASS REVIEW</h1>

  <h2>
  <form action="{% url 'class_review:index' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" name="search_word" size="40">
  <input type="submit" value="search">
</form></h2>
<br/>
  <p>{% for one_review in all_review %}<!--全角スペースを入れる-->　　　　
{{one_review.name}}<br/>
  {% endfor %}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

*style.css*

```
h1 {color: red;}
```

ディレクトリ

```
sns
 |--static
   |--style.css
  --templates
       |--index.html
```

Error内容

```
[14/Oct/2017 17:11:32] "GET /static/class_review/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 103
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

settings.pyに以下の記述を追加しました。

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
(これは最初から記述してありました。)

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',     <-- この行の追加
]

TATIC_URL = '/static/'
(これはもともとありました。)

# Fetch the project_root
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
# /path/to/project_directory/static_file
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    [os.path.join(DJANGO_ROOT, 'static')]
)
```

その上で、htmlファイルを以下のように記述しました。

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{STATIC_URL}}style.css">
```

たぶんこれで表示されたような気がします。

参考ページ
https://qiita.com/okoppe8/items/38688fa9259f261c9440
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/shinriyo/20130814/p4
https://qiita.com/aion/items/add0c983150a2a1e100d

Comment: 「TATIC_URL」は間違いではないですか？